# Error when installing PortAudio through homebrew. (MAC)

Tags: macos, homebrew, speech-recognition, portaudio

I'm attempting to make a speech recognition program with python, but I need to have PyAudio installed, which needs PortAudio. When I try to install PortAudio through Homebrew (The only way it gives me) an error pops up in terminal:

> Updating Homebrew...
>   ==> Homebrew has enabled anonymous aggregate user behaviour analytics. Read the analytics documentation (and how to opt-out) here:
>   https://docs.brew.sh/Analytics.html
>
> xcrun: error: invalid active developer path
>   (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at:
>   /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun Error: Failure while
>   executing: git config --local --replace-all homebrew.analyticsmessage
>   true
>   ==> Tapping homebrew/core xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at:
>   /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun Error: Failure while
>   executing: git clone https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core
>   /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core --depth=1
>   Error: Failure while executing: /usr/local/bin/brew tap homebrew/core

I don't know what to do from here. I could use some help and I was recommended to ask this question on here. Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running

```
xcode-select --install
```

in your terminal, then trying the `homebrew` installation again.

Comment: That worked great! Thank you so much! Just so I know in the future, what made you tell me to run the command?

Comment: I googled `xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools)` and the first two links both suggested running `xcode-select --install`. I remembered running into something similar in the past, so I figured that'd probably work for you.